# Identify a child cell in an array

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

In the following array of 24 rows, there are 9 children (terminal nodes) - shaded yellow for clarity. In other words, every entry has a child except for the terminal nodes. For example, 5E has 2 two terminal nodes. 14G is a terminal node, but 15G is not. 16H is terminal. 17H has 2 children (terminal nodes). 22F also has 2 children (terminal nodes).

[image]

How to write an excel function or macro that identifies these terminal nodes?

Comment: what do you mean by **child cell**? what feature distinguishes them from others?

Comment: That would depend on what you wanted to do with them once you found them. If identifying them is all that matters, a conditional formatting rule should suffice.

Comment: @AHC - realized the ambiguity - have updated the question

Comment: @Jeeped Have tried several conditional formatting techniques but could not make them work. An answer using conditional formatting would be an acceptable answer. Once the terminal nodes are identified, I will add additional data. But for now, all I need to do is identify them in a very large array.

Comment: Had an idea with `=AND(COLUMN(A:A)=MATCH("zzz", $A1:$J1), MATCH("zzz", $A1:$J1)>=MATCH("zzz", $A2:$J2))` but G14 and H16 are showing false positives. Since there could be multiple 'same column' that could still progress somewhere down the line, VBA may be the best if not the only way to go about it. Excel's native formulas simply do not respond well to unknown scope.

Comment: @jeeped Would you propose a VBA, or can you point me to a comparable VBA that I could modify?

Comment: @jeeped Am trying your formula but am getting a FALSE for every comparison. An unambiguous example is 9E.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your data, the following conditional format seems to work.  Select A1:I24, then use this CF formula:

```
=AND(A1<>"",OFFSET(A1,1,1)="")
```

Format with a yellow fill.

**EDIT:**  Here is a screenshot of the CF dialog box, and the worksheet, for clarification:

[image]

Comment: It seems that G14 and H16 are showing false positives.

Comment: The OP wrote *I left off two additional terminal nodes: 14G and 16G*, thought that those cells were, in fact, terminal nodes that he didn't color; and that 16G was a typo referring to 16H  (H16).

Comment: Now I'm definitely confused. I had the same thing occur with my CF rule formula and commented on that point but was not clarified.

Comment: That makes two of us.  Perhaps he will clarify exactly what he means by **terminal node**

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld. Need a bit more help. Am running Excel 2010. Under CF, there are 5 options including Highlight Cell Rules. Which option/sub-option is the one that accepts your formula? For example 'Equal to' does not do what you propose.

Comment: @JayGray - *Use a formula to determine which cells to format*

Comment: @JayGray  *use a formula to decide which cells to format*

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld. Saved me hours of work. This array is a JSON structure where I need to know which row is a terminal node. Your solution is perfect.